# Double selection from xpath scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I want to extract data using xpath with scrapy. This is my code:

```
def parse(self, response):
        Coords = []
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="pitch"]/image[contains(@class,"success")]'):
            item = PogbaItem()
            item['x'] = sel.xpath('@x').extract()
            item['y'] = sel.xpath('@y').extract()
            item['x'] = sel.xpath('@x1').extract()
            item['y'] = sel.xpath('@y1').extract()
            Coords.append(item)
        return Coords
```

The problem is that the html contains two different elements: the first (`image`) with attributes `x,y` and the other (`line`) with attributes `x1,y1`. I'm trying to take and put them together to have a final csv  but i can't find the right xpath  How can i solve that?

**Update**: two examples of `HTML`:

```
<image class="pitch-object timer-1-40 success" x="331.172" y="84.678" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/sites/fourfourtwo.com/modules/custom/statzone/files/icons/successful_clearance.png"></image>

<line class="pitch-object timer-2-84 success" marker-end="url(#smallblue)" x1="453.076" y1="199.169" x2="509.104" y2="216.676" style="stroke:blue;stroke-width:3"></line>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to take as an `x` value `x` attribute if it exists and `x1` otherwise, and same as well for `y`. Here is how I would solve that:

```
item['x'] = sel.xpath('@x').extract_first() or sel.xpath('@x1').extract_first()
item['y'] = sel.xpath('@y').extract_first() or sel.xpath('@y1').extract_first()
```

Or, you can have a pure XPath solution:

```
item['x'] = sel.xpath('(@x|@x1)').extract_first()
item['y'] = sel.xpath('(@y|@y1)').extract_first()
```

And, since you need to handle both `line` and `image` elements, you should adjust your main expression to handle that:

```
//*[@id="pitch"]/*[contains(@class,"success")]
```

Or:

```
//*[@id="pitch"]/*[(self::image or self::line) and contains(@class,"success")]
```

Comment: Sorry i was wrong about the html elements. I just updated my answer

Comment: @slash89mf okay, please see the update. Does it help?

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you!